# Delete modules in a maven project on jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, module

We have some modules which are renamed in our maven build on jenkins:

```
 xx-benchmark (didn’t run)  
 xx-benchmark-service (didn’t run)  
 xx-benchmark-shared (didn’t run)   
 xx-bootstrap (didn’t run)  
 xx-calculation (didn’t run)    
 xx-calculation-service (didn’t run)
```

We want to delete those modules. We used the script [here](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Remove+all+disabled+modules+in+Maven+jobs)   but they were not removed. We tried this script later:

```
import hudson.model.*
import hudson.maven.*

hudson.model.Hudson.instance.items.findAll{job -> job instanceof MavenModuleSet}.each {

  job ->
  println("Job: " + job.name)  
  job.getModules().each {
    module ->
    print("  " + module.name + " (disabled = " + module.disabled + ")")
    if ("someModuleYouNoLongerWant".equals(module.name)) {
      module.delete() 
      println(" <-- deleted module " + module.name)
    } else {
      println("");
    }    
  }  
}
```

But this script was telling us that our modules had: `disabled = false`. How can we disable this module? I can't click them in Jenkins. They seem not to exist but I can not remove them

Answer (score 0):

You should replace the string "someModuleYouNoLongerWant" by the name of a module you want to delete